# Commutativity of Diagram in Top "Lift-like property but for covers"

Tags: general-topology, continuity, category-theory, diagram-chasing

Let $\psi,\chi,\phi$ be continuous functions, with $\psi,\xi$ surjective.  Does there necessarily exists a continuous function $\eta$ such that the diagram commutes in Top:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A @>{\phi}>> B\\
@V{\psi}VV @V{\xi}VV \\
C @>{\eta}>> D
\end{CD}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true even just for functions.  Indeed, if $a,b\in A$ and $c\in C$ are such that $\psi(a)=\psi(b)=c$ but $\xi(\phi(a))\neq \xi(\phi(b))$, then there is no choice of $\eta(c)$ that will make the diagram commute.